# Selective input using scanf. Possible to only read ascii 0x79 and 0x6e

Tags: c, input, ascii, scanf

I was just wondering whether it was possible to do something like this:

```
char yn;

scanf("%79/6ec",yn);
```

so yn can only become either y (0x79) or n (0x6e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No , but you could use scanf to read a char

```
scanf("%c" , &yn );
```

after that you have to check whether it is y/n or illegal input.

```
if ( yn == 'y' ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have now implemented this method, many thanks! I just wondered if there was a shorter way of doing this.

Comment: @user1083734 perhaps `if ( getchar() == 'y' ) {...}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `%[` conversion and do something like this:

```
char yn[2];

if (scanf("%1[yn]", yn) == 1 && yn[0] == 'y')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not sure I understand this %[ conversion though. Can you explain what is happening and why you don't include c but use [yn]??

Comment: the `%[` conversion matches a non-empty string of characters from the specified set (`yn` in this case)

Answer (score 3):

Better way should be to use the scanf scanset like:

```
char c[2];
if( scanf("%1[yn]",c)==1 )
  puts("yn");
else
  puts("not");
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, not sure I understand how this would work though, could you explain it a little more and say what is happening? I don't understand %1[yn]",c?